# Time off in Lieu after training?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

I'm trying to interpret my contact and work out whether I'm entitled to time off in lieu if required to attend training. I normally have a fixed set of working hours per day.

It states that `I may be required to attend training` and that this may `take place outside of normal working hours`. It also states `no additional remuneration` will be provided - but it doesn't say either way whether I can take off time in Lieu.

Does `no additional remuneration` implicitly indicate that I'm not entitled to this?

Comment: Are you an hourly or salaried employee?

Comment: @MichaelC. question didn't associate with my account for some reason. But Salaried.

Answer (score 1):

"No additional remuneration" doesn't mean you won't get paid - it means you won't get paid *extra*. For it being out-of-hours. Work related training *is* work and you are entitled to normal remuneration- if your contract has time-in-lieu provisions then you can use them.

Comment: In this case there isn't any "time in lieu" provision, except when being made to work a bank holiday.